# How can I find and replace between [ ] characters using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, ultraedit

I want to delete strings between [ ] characters by using Notepad++ or Ultraedit

**Will be deleted string**

```
avenged sevenfold [ something ] dear god
```

**That will be just like below**

```
avenged sevenfold dear god
```

I try to delete it just like this pattern :

```
\[[^]]+\]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Works fine for me, did you check `Regex` at the botom of the dialog box?

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression is:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

Note the escaping of the `]` inside the character class.

If you want to take out trailing spaces so that it’s *exactly* like your specification, add a `\s*` to the end of that.